# How to hide script name using returnStdout in Jenkins?

Tags: python, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In my JenkinsFile I execute a python script like this :

```
def TEST = bat (script: '''
                %PYTHON% .\\setVersion.py --path=%WORK_DIR% --version=%RELEASE_NAME% --major=%SRC_VERSION%
                ''', returnStdout: true)
echo "The script displays : ${TEST} and it is wonderful !"
```

This works pretty well except that my ${TEST} variable contains the script name :

```
The script displays : 
w:\root\build>C:\Tools\Python\2.7\python.exe .\setVersion.py --path=w:/root/build --version=guava --major=1.3 
The version will be : guava-1.3.7272
 and it is wonderful !
```

I would like it to display something like this :

```
The script displays : The version will be : guava-1.3.7272 and it is wonderful !
```

I don't know how to do it, I would appreciate some help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `@echo off` at the beginning of script

```
def TEST = bat (script: '''@echo off
                %PYTHON% .\\setVersion.py --path=%WORK_DIR% --version=%RELEASE_NAME% --major=%SRC_VERSION%
                ''', returnStdout: true)
...
```

Comment: Or simply prefix the command with `@`, e. g. `'''@%PYTHON% ...'''`. As a side node, `%PYTHON%` should be enclosed in double-quotation marks in case it has been installed in a path that contains spaces, e. g. `C:\Program Files`.

Comment: After doing those changes, I still had one more small issue : a carriage return was present when I displayed the variable. So I wrote ```def TEST = bat (...).trim()``` and everything work as I wanted ! Thanks again